# Expected symbol problems with this function declaration

Tags: c, qt, cmake

I am just getting back into the C programming realm and I am having an issue that I think is linker related.

I am using cmake for the first time as well, so that could be adding to my frustration.

I have included a third party header file that contains a typedef that my code is trying to use, and it has this line:

```
typedef struct pcap pcap_t;
```

so my code has

```
pcap_t *var;
//later.....
var->fd;// this line throws the error
```

which throws the

```
error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
```

So am I just missing another include file, or is this a linker issue? I am building this code in QtCreator and using cmake. I can dive on a_t to see that typedef declaration in the included header, but I can't seem to dive on "struct a" itself to see where it's coming from.

Thanks

edited the code above to reflect that I am using the pcap libraries

so i have included in my source file's header file the following lines

```
#include <net/bpf.h>
#include <pcap/pcap.h>
```

so I guess between these two includes, I am missing the defintion of the pcap structure. Where can I find it?

Thanks

Comment: The struct came from a standard linux library, and the include is part of my distro

Comment: There's not enough informations to tell something about your problem. Why don't you just post more of your code?

Comment: I will see if I can post more, thanks for taking a look

Comment: Does the header that you got the `typedef` from have an include for `struct a`, or a forward declaration for it?

Comment: Not a linker error, that's a compile time error. You don't have a declaration for `struct a` in scope. You haven't given the compiler enough information to know where to look for `var->member`, so it cannot generate code. You need to include the header which defines `struct a` not just the header which defines the `typedef`.

Comment: i got back to my code - so I can edit the question with the actual types/libs. I will edit for you all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `typedef` statement does two things. It declares the existence of something of type `struct a`. It also declares that `a_t` is an alias for `struct a`. Declaring the existence of a type without any information to determine its size is called by the C language an *incomplete type*. The declaration is colloquially referred to as a *forward declaration*, and the type is colloquially referred to as *opaque* to those parts of the code that never get to see the type's definition.

```
typedef struct a a_t;
a_t *var;
```

The C language allows pointers to an incomplete type to be defined. A pointer to an incomplete type is not itself incomplete, since a pointer to a type is the same size as a void pointer. But, your code then attempts to dereference the pointer:

```
var->member;
```

Since there is no definition of `struct a` available, the compiler has caught an error in your program, and is telling you about it. It is not a linker issue, but a semantic error in your program.

An opaque type is a way to hide implementation details from the user of the type. That is, it is C's way of providing an interface:

```
typedef struct a a_t;

a_t *a_create ();
void a_destroy (a_t *);
int a_get_member (a_t *);
void a_set_member(a_t *, int);
```

Then, in your code, you are expected to use the interface.

```
a_t *var = a_create();
a_set_member(var, 10);
int m = a_get_member(var);
a_destroy(var);
```

The source file that implements the interface would actually define what `struct a` looks like. Since you said you had no definition to reference in your debugger, this likely means you did not provide a definition anywhere in your program.

**Edit:** It seems you are trying to use the packet capture library. You will need to include the `<pcap.h>` header file to your code, and link with `-lpcap`. If the header file or library does not exist, you will need to install the packet capture development package for your OS. The `<pcap.h>` has made a typedef for `pcap_t` already, and it is intentionally opaque. So you will have to use the interfaces the header file defines to access the information you want.

Comment: Thank you for the nice explanation. I edited the question after getting back to my code to seeing the actually libraries I have included. Do you know where those definitions are to be found?

Comment: is pcap.h different than pcap/pcap.h? I seem to be able to find a lot of include files in /usr/include that seem to have similar content

Comment: @Derek: On my system, I only have `<pcap.h>`, and no `<pcap/pcap.h>`, but different systems are different, so I am not sure I can help more than that.